# Connect to two OpenVPN servers at the same time

Tags: openvpn

The [docs here](https://openvpn.net/vpn-server-resources/connecting-to-access-server-with-linux/) say:

> The openvpn package supports the option to connect to multiple OpenVPN servers at the same time.

That's what I would like to do, but it is not as straight-forward as running the openvpn command twice with two different client configs.

Once the first tunnel is established, all traffic goes over that tunnel and my attempted second tunnel fails with `TLS handshake failed`

The output is like this:

```
Tue Jun 18 22:42:55 2019 TCP connection established with [AF_INET]111.222.333.444:443
Tue Jun 18 22:42:55 2019 TCP_CLIENT link local: (not bound)
Tue Jun 18 22:42:55 2019 TCP_CLIENT link remote: [AF_INET]111.222.333.444:443
Tue Jun 18 22:43:56 2019 TLS Error: TLS key negotiation failed to occur within 60 seconds (check your network connectivity)
Tue Jun 18 22:43:56 2019 TLS Error: TLS handshake failed
Tue Jun 18 22:43:56 2019 Fatal TLS error (check_tls_errors_co), restarting
Tue Jun 18 22:43:56 2019 SIGUSR1[soft,tls-error] received, process restarting
Tue Jun 18 22:43:56 2019 Restart pause, 5 second(s)
```

That repeats with the same error until I kill the process.

Our location has a Linux-based firewall-router and all Internet traffic is routed through a VPN tunnel. This has been working properly for several years.

Now we are adding a remote location with servers we can only access via VPN. Therefore, we need a second VPN tunnel running on our Linux-based firewall-router. I'm not sure how to set that up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the moment your description sounds like you have all traffic routed over the VPN tunnel.

To use two (or more) simultaneous tunnels, you need to define which networks are to be routed via which VPN tunnel. You can have networks a,b,c routed through VPN 1 and networks x,y,z routed through VPN 2. Or everything except x,y,z routed through VPN 1 and x,y,z routed through VPN 2, etc.

Once you've done that, add some detail to your question and we can help you with specifics.